# Rails - Getting the last X records back from the current record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails I have a model message: id, content

I want to run a query that does something the along the lines of.

if the current @message.content, is equal to any @message.content that was created_at less than 10 mins from now, return true else return false.

How would I go about structing an activerecord lookup like that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try doing this

```
Message.exists?(["created_at >= ? and content = ?", @message.created_at.advance(:minutes => -10), @message.content])
```

more info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects)

Comment: That good but it does not exclude the current item, so it will always be true, right?

Comment: oops, my bad, try: Message.exists?(["id <> ? and created_at >= ? and content = ?", @message.id, @message.created_at.advance(:minutes => -10), @message.content])